# out of memory E/DartVM ( 2745): Exhausted heap space, trying to allocate 64 bytes

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-method-channel

// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors, file_names, prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables, use_full_hex_values_for_flutter_colors

> this is the code

`import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RowItemsWidget extends StatelessWidget {
const RowItemsWidget({super.key});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return SingleChildScrollView(
scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
child: Row(children: [
for (int i = 1; 1 < 4; i++)
Container(
margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
height: 160,
decoration: BoxDecoration(
color: Color(0xfff5f9fd),
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
boxShadow: [
BoxShadow(
color: Color(0xff47569).withOpacity(0.3),
blurRadius: 5,
spreadRadius: 1,
)
]),
child: Row(children: [
Stack(
alignment: Alignment.center,
children: [
Container(
margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, right: 10),
height: 110,
width: 120,
decoration: BoxDecoration(
color: Color(0xFF475269),
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
),
),
Image.asset(
"images/1.png",
height: 150,
width: 150,
fit: BoxFit.contain,
)
],
),
Padding(
padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30),
child: Column(
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
children: [
Text(
'Nike Shoe',
style: TextStyle(
color: Color(0xff475269),
fontSize: 23,
fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
),
),
SizedBox(
height: 1,
),
Text(
"Men's Shoe",
style: TextStyle(
color: Color(0xff475269).withOpacity(0.8),
fontSize: 16),
)
]),
),
// Spacer(),
SizedBox(width: 0),

> ! Row(<sub>your text</sub>
> children: [
> Padding(
> padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
> child: Text(
> "$50",
> style: TextStyle(
> color: Colors.redAccent,
> fontSize: 20,
> fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
> ),
> ),
> ),
> SizedBox(width: 1),
> Container(
> padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
> decoration: BoxDecoration(
> color: Color(0xff475269),
> borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
> child: Icon(
> CupertinoIcons.cart_fill_badge_plus,
> color: Colors.white,
> size: 25,
> ),
> ),
> ],
> )
> ]),
> )
> ]),
> );
> }
> }`

Comment: Please format your code so that it is readable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: Exhausted heap space, trying to allocate 8589934608 bytes and laptop stops responding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61674754/flutter-exhausted-heap-space-trying-to-allocate-8589934608-bytes-and-laptop-st)